Use v-for of number to load multiple <img>
I have an index.vue page that sends title (string) and picCount(number) to ShowPics.vue components.
I have multiple pics in assets\pics\gilmore_girls\ , like pic attached
assets\pics\gilmore_girls\ 
Here's index.vue:
<template>
  <ShowPics
      :title="routeName"
      :picCount="picCount"
  ></ShowPics>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const route = useRoute();
const routeName = ref('');
const picCount: number = 15;

if (route.name) {
  routeName.value = typeof route.name === 'string'
      ? route.name
      : route.name.toString();
  console.log('index ', routeName.value);
} else {
  routeName.value = 'Not Defined';
}
</script>

here's ShowPics.vue component:
<template>
  <div v-if="picCount > 0" v-for="num in picCount">
    <img
        :key="num"
        :src="`/assets/pics/${title}/${title}_${num}.jpg`"
        alt=""
        loading="lazy"
    />
    <p>/assets/pics/{{ title }}/{{ title }}_{{ num }}.jpg</p>
  </div>
  <p v-else>No Pics</p>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const props = defineProps<{
  title: string;
  picCount: number;
}>();

console.log('showpic Title : ', props.title);
console.log('showpic picCount : ', props.picCount);
</script>

I expected all of the pictures to be shown on the page, but it shows an error message "Not Found" instead.

Assuming your build tool is Vite, see this answer.  the src URLs need to be constructed in the script setup block.  you can send the v-for information to a function that returns the correct new URL()
